# is there a function to Delete a firestore collection and all documents in it in javascript like deleteDocument()?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

this provided function deletes only a document and leaves it's subcollections and nested data in the firestore DB

```
firestore.deleteDocument("Document/path/here");
```

is there a function in javascript the does the delete operation but also for all the nested data in the document?

right now i am using this code to do the job

```
for(var j =0; j < source.length; j++){
      firestore.deleteDocument("Document/path/here/" + source[i][j]);
    }
```

Comment: For web clients, no.  For nodejs backends, read the duplicate.

Comment: i did, but i was looking for a solution more effecient than mine and the duplicate solution does not work for me...

Comment: You really don't have any other options.